# jQuery: Multiple draggables and droppables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use jquery draggable and droppable.

I have multiple draggables and multiple droppables on my page.

The drga and drop works fine but the issue is that when I drag and drop a div onto 1 droppable, it will get cloned in other droppables on my page as well... also, when I move the draggables inside the droppables, they get multiplied again.

To explain this issue, I've created this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qkhunz8k/1/)

and this is my entire code:

```
(function ($) {
   $.fn.liveDraggable = function (opts) {
      this.live("mouseover", function() {
         if (!$(this).data("init")) {
            $(this).data("init", true).draggable(opts);
         }
      });
      return this;
   };
}(jQuery));
$('.drag').liveDraggable({
    helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move'


        });


var x = null;
$(".droppable").droppable({
  drop: function(e, ui) {
    var parent = $(".droppable");
    var x = ui.helper.clone();
    var img = $(x)

    var leftAdj = (ui.position.left - parent.offset().left);
    var topAdj = (ui.position.top - parent.offset().top);


    if (x.hasClass("outside")) {
      x.css({
        left: leftAdj,
        top: topAdj
      });
      x.removeClass("outside");

    }

    x.draggable({
      helper: 'original'
    });
    x.find('.ui-resizable-handle').remove();
    x.resizable();
    x.appendTo('.droppable');
    ui.helper.remove();
  }
});
```

Drag the red divs onto the black divs and you should see the issue.

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Getting close but still not quite there: https://jsfiddle.net/qkhunz8k/2/

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Apparently I'm not communicating very well. Let me try this again. All of your droppables have the class `droppable`. As you say, of course they do. That is the purpose of the class.

However, in your code, when you say `x.appendTo('.droppable')`, this is the source of your duplicates. It is appending to every element which has the `droppable` class.

I'm not suggesting that you change or remove the droppable class. I'm not suggesting that you change all of your jquery selectors. I'm only suggesting that when you do your `.appendTo`, perhaps you should only be appending it to the `droppable` which is the target. Not all of them. Does that make sense? You can do this by doing `x.appendTo(this)`. Just change that one line, and see if the duplicate problem goes away.

```
    $(".droppable").droppable({
...
        x.appendTo(this);
```

The only thing this change will do is change the number of elements your draggable gets appended to. It wouldn't cause any other changes. But I think it will solve your original problem.

As an aside, might I suggest that you would get better results by changing one other line? If you were to use the `ui.draggable` instead of the `ui.helper`, you might find that the css positioning would be a little easier to manage, and that you wouldn't need to manipulate the `top` and `left` properties so much. Just a thought.

```
var x = ui.draggable.clone();
```

updated modification of your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qkhunz8k/10/)

Comment: 'All of your droppables have class droppable.'.. yes, ofcourse they have. that is what class is for! and sorry but your fiddle is still not what I'm trying to do. in your fiddle, once the drag is dragged once, it will become un-draggable.

Comment: Okay, the idea is that when you do this: `$('.droppable')`, that represents ALL elements which have the class. So if you append to that jQuery, it will append to all. That's why you should be appending to the `$(this)` element. The problem you expressed was that the element was being appended to multiple targets when you dropped it. This is why that is happening.

Comment: I've tried to clarify my answer a bit, to explain. I hope it is a little more clear now. Also, I'm not sure exactly what you mean when you say "once the drag is dragged once, it will become un-draggable." Are you saying that the original draggables can't be dragged? Or the appended clones? I've tried in both firefox and chrome, and am able to drag the original draggables many times. The clones seem to be limited to being dragged within their new droppable container, but I'm not exactly sure if this is what you mean, and for that matter what you want it to do.